# How would I define a function for this? [Noob question]

Tags: python

I´m working on creating a list for a game I play with my friends where words get added x times to that list.
Currently, I´m using the same three lines of code 5 times and I´d like to instead just call up a predefined funtion 5 times. is that possible? (I only translated the first line)

```
AmountApple = int(input("How many apples?"))
for num in range(AmountApple):
    newList.append("apple")
    
AnzahlW2 = int(input("Wie viele Werwolf2?"))
for num in range(AnzahlW2):
    Rollen.append("Werwolf2")
    
AnzahlA = int(input("Wie viele Amor?"))
for num in range(AnzahlA):
    Rollen.append("Amor")
    
AnzahlHexe = int(input("Wie viele Hexe?"))
for num in range(AnzahlHexe):
    Rollen.append("Hexe")
    
AnzahlHure = int(input("Wie viele Hure"))
for num in range(AnzahlHure):
    Rollen.append("Hure")

AnzahlB = int(input("Wie viele Bürger"))
for num in range(AnzahlB):
    Rollen.append("Bürger")
```

Any help or pointing out where I mightve gone wrong would be appreciated!

Comment: You could use a list to store the custom input strings and use a loop using the list's elements as input strings for each iteration.

Comment: Are you aware of how to write your own function in Python?

Comment: I am an Austrian and therefore I understand the Word `Hure`. I do not exactly know If this is forbidden at SO, but I dont think you should use it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bigger sample of your script maybe would have helped, but from my understanding of your script if I had this problem I would do this:

```
def fruitFunction(fruit, newList):
    amountFruit = int(input(f"How many {fruit}?"))
    for amount in range(amountFruit):
        newList.append(fruit)

    return newList
```

You can see that I used f-strings here. f-strings allow you to put variables in strings without having to use `+` or `,` and have lots of double-quotes. I recommend that you use f-strings everywhere you can.

There is a problem though, and that's the fact that you need to know the singular and plural of the fruit. But it can be solved like this:

```
def fruitFunction(singularFruit, pluralFruit, newList):
    amountFruit = int(input(f"How many {pluralFruit}?"))
    for amount in range(amountFruit):
        newList.append(singularFruit)

    return newList
```

To use this function you just have to do this: `newList = fruitFunction('apple', 'apples', newList)`
Keep in mind that you have to have a list already made to call this function.

Also, it might be a good idea to instead of adding a fruits name 5 times for example in the list, you can append a list to the list. The list would contain the name of the fruit and the amount. It can be done like this:

```
amountFruit = int(input(f"How many {fruit}?"))
newList.append([fruit, amountFruit])
```

And that should work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does the one snippet:

```
def add_to_list(my_text, rollen):
    n = int(input("Wie viele " + my_text + "?"))
    for i in range(n):
         rollen.append(my_text)

    return rollen
```

You can then call the function like so, as many times as you need and with different words:

```
Rollen = add_to_list("Amor", Rollen)
Rollen = add_to_list("Hexe", Rollen)
```

Note that `Rollen` needs to be defined before you call the function.